# Raspberry, check electric current

Tags: raspberry-pi, iot, sensors

I've searched for many hours a way to detect if electric current is flowing or not using a Raspberry without success.

The problem that I'm facing up is, using a Raspberry (powered by an uninterruptible power supply), detect if electric current in my house is ON or not. 
Sometimes the electric current goes down because we've too many devices connected and when the fridge is down for some days is not a good surprise when you discover this.

Do someone have a solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about upgrading to 6kW contract? :) Just joking

What about a step down 220v to 3,3V converter connected to a GPIO pin as input?

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/AC-DC-110V-220V-to-3-3V-700mA-2-3W-Switching-Switch-Power-Supply-Buck-Converter/32833671094.html

Well, actually maybe better use an optocoupler to stay safe with isolation:

https://www.ebay.it/itm/240V-220V-AC-Mains-Sensor-opto-isolator-optoisolator-optocoupler-5V-3-3V-Arduino/272619019157

Just be sure to have a 3,3V as output, use a level shifter if this guy gives you a 5V as output.
And always be careful when playing around with the mains!

Comment: And about upgrading to 6kW is not enough when there's a storm and you are away from home :D

Comment: But then what are you doing with your stuff in the fridge? Maybe you remove the element of surprise... but things will go rotten anyway...

Comment: You're right but I feel better if I know in real time what is happening, also if are bad things..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detect voltage, you can use one of the GPIOs set in input mode. The huge caveat is that GPIOs work of 3.5V low current DC, mains is 220V or 110V AC (depends which country) so you will probably need a Mains -> 3.5V DC supply between the mains and the RPI.